# Побитовые операции в Си

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Есть задача, на побитовые операции. Условия задачи:
Удалить цифру 1 в записи данного восьмеричного числа.
Не до конца понимаю, как это реализовать при помощи побитовых операций.
Например число 213 превратиться в 23

Comment: Что означает "удалить"?

Comment: Например число 213, измениться на 23

Comment: Идете по три бита, если это 001 — сдвиг...

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте ваши попытки решения, так у нас здесь принято.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разряд восьмеричного числа занимает 3 бита.
Достаточно пройтись по разрядам числа со вставкой в результат всех цифр, кроме 1.

Пример реализации:

```
#include <cstdlib>    
unsigned int skip_ones_in_oct(unsigned int x){
        unsigned int res=0;
        int i=0; // счетчик разрядов выходного чиcла
        while (x>0){
          std::div_t qr = div(x, 8); // получаем делитель и остаток
          if (qr.rem != 1){ // остаток rem - это последняя цифра восьмиричного числа
            res = res +(qr.rem << 3*i); // добавляем цифру в очередной разряд
            i++; // увеличиваем разряд
          }
          x = qr.quot; // убираем младший разряд исходного числа
        }
        return res;
}
```

Comment: Портите мне воспитательную работу. >:c

Comment: div и `*` - это не битовые операции.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

`x & 7` - младшая цифра числа, например `123` -> `3`.

`x >> 3` - число без младшей цифры, например `123` -> `12`.

`x << 3` - добавляет ноль справа, например `123` -> `1230`

`(x << 3) | y` - добавляет произольную цифру справа, например `123`, `4` -> `1234`.

Дальше сами.